# Maui Hide Status bar in IOS 13+

Tags: ios, maui, maui-community-toolkit

The code below works but it is obsolete. I am looking for a better solution.

```
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarHidden(shouldBeFullScreen, animation: UIKit.UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade);
```

I need to use `UIViewController PrefersStatusBarHidden();`

I have tried:

```
UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();

        var vc = window?.RootViewController ?? WindowStateManager.Default.GetCurrentUIViewController() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(window.RootViewController)} cannot be null");
        while (vc.PresentedViewController is not null)
        {
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
        }
            vc.PrefersStatusBarHidden();
            vc.SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
```

The above code does grab the window but it does not actually hide the status bar.

I have also tried:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.Page.SetPrefersStatusBarHidden(currentPage, item);
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. I am working on implementing full screen controls in Media Element for Community toolkit and I am stuck on hiding the status bar in IOS.

Comment: Then prefersStatusBarHidden method in current viewController should be overridden

Comment: Overriding prefersStatusBarHidden is the preferred method. I just can't figure out how to do that. I can get the current view controller I just don't know how to override the PrefersStatusBarHidden method.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines into your info.plist file. Right click on info.plist and select **Open As** then choose **Source Code**

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: That does work. I need to be able to switch the status bar on and off as I switch into full screen and out of full screen. Your solution will make it so the status bar is always disabled. I am looking for solution that allows me to switch it on and off on demand.

Answer (score 0):

[**prefersStatusBarHidden**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiviewcontroller.prefersstatusbarhidden?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#uikit-uiviewcontroller-prefersstatusbarhidden) is a virtual method of UIViewController and should be overridden in current UIViewController you want to change the status bar. One way is to create a new UIViewController for that page, but that means
you have to write all controls in a native way. That may cause more troubles.

Or you may refer to this thread: [iOS PageRenderer compatibility not rendering page content](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7174) and [PureWeen commented](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7174#issuecomment-1505519377). Here is a simple demo:

In iOS folder, you may create a **HideStatusBarPageHandler** which inherit PageHandler.

```
public class HideStatusBarPageHandler : PageHandler
{
    class MainPageViewController : PageViewController
    {
        public bool IsStatusBarHidden { get; set; }

        public MainPageViewController(IView page, IMauiContext mauiContext) : base(page, mauiContext)
        {
        }
        
        // in this viewController, override the method which returns a variable that we could set true or false to it
        public override bool PrefersStatusBarHidden()
        {
            return IsStatusBarHidden;
        }
    }
    
    // the following code is from PureWeen commented with small changes
    protected override Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView CreatePlatformView()
    {
        _ = VirtualView ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(VirtualView)} must be set to create a LayoutView");
        _ = MauiContext ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(MauiContext)} cannot be null");

        if (ViewController == null)
            ViewController = new MainPageViewController(VirtualView, MauiContext);

        if (ViewController is PageViewController pc && pc.CurrentPlatformView is Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView pv)
            return pv;

        if (ViewController.View is Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView cv)
            return cv;

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"PageViewController.View must be a {nameof(Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView)}");
    }
}
```

In MauiProgram.cs, add the handler:

```
    builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
    {
#if IOS
        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(MainPage),typeof(HideStatusBarPageHandler));
#endif
    });
```

Then when you get the Current ViewControl, you could control the show or hide of status bar by change the IsStatusBarHidden property.

```
vc.IsStatusBarHidden = !vc.IsStatusBarHidden;
vc.SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
```

Hope it works.